# Script in dependency needs path to Composer autoloader

Tags: php, autoload, composer-php

I am developing a package - `myvendor/mylib` - that I plan to distribute using Composer, probably via Packagist. This package contains - among other things - a commandline PHP script `bin/console.php` that I would like to make available to projects - say `myvendor/mymain` - that import the `mylib` package.

I am aware that I can specify in the `mylib` package a `config` setting in `composer.json` with an array of bins to import:

```
{
    "name": "myvendor/mylib",
    "config" : {
        "bin" : ["bin/console.php"]
    }
}
```

When the `mymain` project does a composer install/update, then this `mylib/bin/console.php` is symlinked as `mymain/bin/console.php` Further, I am aware that the `mymain` project can specify - in his own `composer.json` - where *he* wants dependency bins to be symlinked:

```
{
    "name": "myvendor/mymain",
    "config": {
        "bin-dir": "scripts"
    }   
}
```

In this case, the console script is then symlinked as `scripts/console.php`.

This works fine - and is cool as as all get out, by the way. ;-)

However, the script `bin/console.php` itself needs to include the Composer-generated `vendor/autoloader.php`. When developing `mylib` in isolation, the script `bin/console.php` knows his own location relative to `vendor/autoloader.php`, so he can include it easily. But once it is imported as a dependency into another project - `myvendor/mymain`, in this case - then there is only the `mymain/vendor/autoloader.php` script. In principle, the console script cannot know where he resides relative to that autoloader script.

Does Composer provide some environment variable - accessible to the console script - that allows the script to locate the right `vendor/autoloader.php` script?

BTW: I am aware of the [Composer CLI environment variable](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#environment-variables), so I imagine I could make it a requirement that the importing project - `mymain` - define (and export!) the var `COMPOSER_VENDOR_DIR`. Then my console script can use that to find the project's autoloader. But that seems potentially problematic in that:

1. We want the setting to apply only to *this* project, but a shell var (and an export) would apply to *all* projects accessed from that shell session. Seems presumptuous of my little dependency - `myvendor/mylib` - to impose that on an importing project.
2. In principle, the dependency itself - `myvendor/mylib` - should be able to find what he needs. Doesn't seem right to put the onus on the importer.

WDYT? Thanks in advance. Ideas welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach (that came out of discussions with @igorw on IRC freenode #composer that I am paraphrasing and on which I am somewhat expanding) is to let the bin script `console.php` iterate up the filesystem, starting from `__DIR__`, looking for the presence of `autoload.php`.

Comment: You do not need to iterate really, you can just look two dirs up since that would match <vendor-name>/<package-name>/

Comment: @Seldaek: Right, I finally understood your sample from [jsonlint](https://github.com/Seldaek/jsonlint/blob/master/bin/jsonlint) and implemented that way. Thanks mucho!

Comment: Seems people are still having issues with this (me!) 
Found an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35271282/how-can-i-provide-a-script-for-php-cli-via-composer-as-standalone-and-as-depen